# Log unhandled exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

I have been trying to log this exception for days but cant figure it out. So I thought I post it here with the hope that someone could help. I have also posted some of my code that I'm currently using to catch unhandled exceptions but the exception never showed up in the log file.

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

> Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
>     Application Name: Myapp.exe
>     Application Version:  1.0.0.0
>     Application Timestamp:    52e9aab8
>     Fault Module Name:    clr.dll
>     Fault Module Version: 4.0.30319.18052
>     Fault Module Timestamp:   5173c26b
>     Exception Code:   c00000fd
>     Exception Offset: 00372b52
>     OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
>     Locale ID:    1033
>     Additional Information 1: 5cff
>     Additional Information 2: 5cfff2c5825852a6f100872ec6f038a2
>     Additional Information 3: a2a3
>     Additional Information 4: a2a3734c473189c5efabc88b5081d05a

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += CurrentOnDispatcherUnhandledException;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
    Dispatcher.UnhandledException += DispatcherOnUnhandledException;
    InitializeComponent();          
}

private void DispatcherOnUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.Exception;
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("ExceptionsLog.txt"))
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        writer.WriteLine("Time {0} Exception: {1}", time, e);
        writer.Flush();
    }
    args.Handled = true;
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}

private void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("ExceptionsLog.txt"))
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        writer.WriteLine("Time {0} Exception: {1} Runtime termination: {2}", time, e.Message, args.IsTerminating);
        writer.Flush();
    }
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}

private void CurrentOnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.Exception;
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("ExceptionsLog.txt"))
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        writer.WriteLine("Time {0} Exception: {1}", time, e);
        writer.Flush();
    }
    args.Handled = true;
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `c00000fd` is a stackoverflow. Presumably the lack of stack space is what prevented it from being logged.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For handling unhandled exceptions, please create a method like this

```
   protected TResult LogFailedOperations<TResult>(Func<TResult> action)
        {
            try
            {
                return action();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Logic for logging from ex.Message
            }
        }
```

Also, when you perform any method, just enclose that method around this `LogFailedOperations` method like these examples -

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var result = LogFailedOperations(() => { /* Your logic for button click */ });
}

private void LoadDataToView()
{
  var result = LogFailedOperations(() => { /* Your logic for laoding data */ });
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
  var result = LogFailedOperations(() => { /* Your logic for slider changed event */ });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why OP should do this?

Comment: This method can be used to execute every code block in a try catch block which will log the exception. If it is not done, then possibly there are chances of missing out exceptions.